# How to intuit of weak solutions and classical solutions?

Tags: distribution-theory

> [Vibrating String equation]
>
> $$\partial_{tt} u = k^2 \partial_{xx}u$$
>
> Both sides of the equation are meaningful if $u$ is a distribution. If the equality holds, we call $u$ a weak solution. If $u$ is continously differentiable and the equality holds, we call $u$ a classical solution.
>
> page-21, Guide to Distribution Theory and Fourier transforms.

I'm a bit confused on how exactly these two solutions differ. Could someone who is more learned about this topic explain what picture they have in their head when they think of these two categorizations of solutions? Thanks.

Comment: We call $u$ a weak solution if $u$ is a distribution and equality holds in the sense of distributions. Recall that $u$ and $v$ are equal as distributions if $u(\varphi) = v(\varphi)$ holds for all smooth, compactly supported functions $\varphi$. In this case, $u$ may not correspond to a function at all (i.e. may not be defined pointwise) and the derivatives must be interpreted as distributional derivatives. If $u$ corresponds to a function, and this function is differentiable in the usual sense and satisfies the equation, then we say that it is a classical solution.